# Como utilizar un Array de fechas GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY dentro de un IN en BigQuery

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, google-bigquery

Estoy intentando crear un array de fechas para ponerlo dentro de un IN en un PIVOT tal que asi

```
PIVOT (SUM(num_calls) FOR call_day IN (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2023-10-15', '2023-10-25')))
```

Pero no es posible creo que es debido a que dentro del IN no es posible utilizar el subquery en BigQuery, tengo este error **Syntax error: Unexpected keyword SELECT**, este es  el query

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT extension,
        email,
        team_vanex,
        call_type,
        ROUND(avg_num_calls) AS avg_num_calls,
        num_calls,
        call_day
        FROM calls_by_executive AS cx 
        JOIN avg_calls AS ac ON ac.email_avg = cx.email) 
PIVOT (SUM(num_calls) FOR call_day IN (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2023-10-15', '2023-10-25')))
```

Otra cosa que probe fue quemando los datos directamente funciona, pero necesito que sea a eleccion del usuario las fechas dentro del GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY

```
PIVOT (SUM(num_calls) FOR call_day IN ('2023-10-01', '2023-10-02', '2023-10-03', '2023-10-04', '2023-10-05', '2023-10-06', '2023-10-07', '2023-10-08', '2023-10-09'))
```